# Managed memory leaked by C# iterator

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, iterator, garbage-collection

I have a class that generates DNA sequences, that are represented by long strings. This class implements the `IEnumerable<string>` interface, and it can produce an infinite number of DNA sequences. Below is a simplified version of my class:

```
class DnaGenerator : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _enumerable;

    public DnaGenerator() => _enumerable = Iterator();

    private IEnumerable<string> Iterator()
    {
        while (true)
            foreach (char c in new char[] { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' })
                yield return new String(c, 10_000_000);
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

This class generates the DNA sequences by using an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators). Instead of invoking the iterator again and again, an `IEnumerable<string>` instance is created during the construction and is cached as a private field. The problem is that using this class results in a sizable chunk of memory being constantly allocated, with the [garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc) being unable to recycle this chunk. Here is a minimal demonstration of this behavior:

```
var dnaGenerator = new DnaGenerator();
Console.WriteLine($"TotalMemory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):#,0} bytes");
DoWork(dnaGenerator);
GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine($"TotalMemory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):#,0} bytes");
GC.KeepAlive(dnaGenerator);

static void DoWork(DnaGenerator dnaGenerator)
{
    foreach (string dna in dnaGenerator.Take(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing DNA of {dna.Length:#,0} nucleotides" +
            $", starting from {dna[0]}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TotalMemory: 84,704 bytes
Processing DNA of 10,000,000 nucleotides, starting from A
Processing DNA of 10,000,000 nucleotides, starting from C
Processing DNA of 10,000,000 nucleotides, starting from G
Processing DNA of 10,000,000 nucleotides, starting from T
Processing DNA of 10,000,000 nucleotides, starting from A
TotalMemory: 20,112,680 bytes
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jZIfC3).

My expectation was that all generated DNA sequences would be eligible for garbage collection, since they are not referenced by my program. The only reference that I hold is the reference to the `DnaGenerator` instance itself, which is not meant to contain any sequences. This component just generates the sequences. Nevertheless, no matter how many or how few sequences my program generates, there are always around 20 MB of memory allocated after a full garbage collection.

**My question is:** Why is this happening? And how can I prevent this from happening?

.NET 6.0, Windows 10, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor, Release built.

---

**Update:** The problem disappears if I replace this:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
```

...with this:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => Iterator().GetEnumerator();
```

But I am not a fan of creating a new enumerable each time an enumerator is needed. My understanding is that a single [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) can create many [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1)s. AFAIK these two interfaces are not meant to have an one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Part of your problem is probably the `yield return` statement, as it needs to internally cache the state of the loop. I'm assuming the enumerators stay in scope due to the compiler tricks that are necessary to make `yield return` work.

Comment: As long as `dnaGenerator` is in memory, so will the `_enumerable` variable be, unless you are clearing it explicitly.

Comment: @AamirMasood yes, you are right. But the `_enumerable` is not supposed to prevent the garbage collection of the DNA sequences. It is supposed to generate them, not store them. Unless you mean that the `_enumerable` requires 20 MB of memory by itself, for its internal workings.

Comment: May I give you another advise: in this line:  
```while (true)
            foreach (char c in new char[] { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' })
                yield return new String(c, 10_000_000);```
replace the "new char[] {.....}" with "stackalloc char[] {.....} " and you remove 1 source of unnessecary garbage collection

Comment: @Shpendicus the code in the `Iterator()` is just a demo. An actual DNA generator would be much more sophisticated. Thanks for the advice anyway, it might be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias  oh okay lol, but maybe you can still make some use of it at any point :-D gl tho cool program!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 10_000_000 of chars (which are 16 bit) will take approximately 20 MB. If you will take a look at the [`decompilation`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUO1wAwAIQQHQGED2AbXApgMYAuAltgHYDOA3LCCmgCz1KoYAyZlAjm7GRDUYZABFKAQwDiBSgQBOkktgXIAXBwDMAHjSIAfIOEBvY8OEAHBWQBuygsgUFJAEyq4Antr0RDyAH05AFcAW0VJACNCARgLCxAtcSlZeSUVBQAKAEpkAF4DQJDwpWjHPOQASRIIjJzY+KsbexqffULq2tUc83izGABIIfs1Imp85HkAd2QiAAtJBQBtAF1kE2QAcgBBTYAaLcx9reljzYAVTeQAXzZGxqm5skJkTJIFYIJs3vv4gDNVC55q95otZsgeLNqN84r84UI0BBUAB2SYEGb6TJEA5+AKIfF4/HZO73a6wH7CRJVACilDCXQUvn8shItPp6W6uQKRTpJSihHQLLZfLqxIpQkqwoZ2kFBFZvIZOXyhSFCo5WTFsKE1yAA) you will notice that `yeild return` results in internal `<Iterator>` class generated which in turn has a `current` field to store the string (to implement `IEnumerator<string>.Current`):

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <Iterator>d__2 : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<string>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
​    ...
    private string <>2__current;
    ...
}
```

And `Iterator` method internally will be compiled to something like this:

```
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<Iterator>d__2))]
private IEnumerable<string> Iterator()
{
    return new <Iterator>d__2(-2);
}
```

Which leads to the current string always being stored in memory for `_enumerable.GetEnumerator();` implementation (after iteration start) while `DnaGenerator` instance is not GCed itself.

**UPD**

> My understanding is that a single IEnumerable can create many IEnumerators. AFAIK these two interfaces are not meant to have an one-to-one relationship.

Yes, in case of generated for `yield return` enumerable it can create multiple enumerators, but in this particular case the implementation have "one-to-one" relationship because the generated implementation is both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`:

```cs
private sealed class <Iterator>d__2 : 
    IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable,
    IEnumerator<string>, IEnumerator, 
    IDisposable
```

> But I am not a fan of creating a new enumerable each time an enumerator is needed.

But it is actually what is happening when you call `_enumerable.GetEnumerator()` (which is obviously an implementation detail), if you check already mentioned decompilation you will see that `_enumerable = Iterator()` is actually `new <Iterator>d__2(-2)` and `<Iterator>d__2.GetEnumerator()` looks something like this:

```
IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
{
    if (<>1__state == -2 && <>l__initialThreadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
    {
        <>1__state = 0;
        return this;
    }
    return new <Iterator>d__2(0);
}
```

So it actually should create a new iterator instance every time except the first enumeration, so your `public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => Iterator().GetEnumerator();` approach is just fine.

Comment: Nice explanation! Do you know if there is any way to set the `<>2__current = default;` when the `IDisposable.Dispose()` is called?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I believe there is not, at least based on the decompilation code. The only option I see (while keeping the current implementation) is to clear `_enumerable` field of `DnaGenerator` when needed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias please see the update.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So it seems that if I am enumerating the enumerable multiple times, but always on the same thread on which is was created, all these enumerations will use the same autogenerated enumerable+enumerator instance all the times. This is an argument for changing the type of my `_enumerable` field to `ThreadLocal<IEnumerable<string>>`. But if I do that, then I'll probably have the same memory leak, multiplied by the number of threads that have enumerated at least once my `DnaGenerator` class!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias either I don't understand you or they will not. They will use the same instance to create a new instance which will actually be used by the code enumerating stuff. i.e. sequential calls to `dnaGenerator.GetEnumerator()` will give you different instances of generated class - `object.ReferenceEquals(dnaGenerator.GetEnumerator(),dnaGenerator.GetEnumerator())` will always be `false`. i,e. just do `DnaGenerator.GetEnumerator() => Iterator().GetEnumerator()` and don't bother.

Comment: Oou, yes, you are right. I was assuming that the `<>1__state` was restored to `-2` after a complete enumeration, but after reading the autogenerated code (the link inside your answer) more carefully, this does not happen. So my previous comment is completely incorrect. :-)

Comment: I think that you proved that my attempt to be smart with the `private readonly IEnumerable<string> _enumerable;` field is the cause of my problems. Not only it offers no advantage whatsoever, but it can also cause a memory leak from the non-cleaned `<>2__current` field. So your answer is currently my prime candidate for awarding the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by the auto-generated implementation for the code using `yield`.

You can mitigate this somewhat by explicitly implementing the enumerator.

You have to fiddle it a bit by calling `.Reset()` from `public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()` to ensure the enumeration restarts at each call:

```
class DnaGenerator : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<string> _enumerable;

    public DnaGenerator() => _enumerable = new IteratorImpl();

    sealed class IteratorImpl : IEnumerator<string>
    {
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return true; // Infinite sequence.
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _index = 0;
        }

        public string Current
        {
            get
            {
                var result = new String(_data[_index], 10_000_000);

                if (++_index >= _data.Length)
                    _index = 0;

                return result;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Nothing to do.
        }

        readonly char[] _data = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };

        int _index;

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        _enumerable.Reset();
        return _enumerable;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew! It's a bit disappointing though that I have to implement an `IEnumerator<string>` from scratch. The iterators are much more convenient!

Answer (score 1):

If memory usage (or speed) is an concern, you might (also) want to use bytes (or ints) to represent 4 nucleotides at once. Given what you shared with us, that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

@GuruStron's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72473558/11178549) demonstrated that the problem that I've presented here was created by my shallow understanding of the C# iterators, and of how they are implemented internally. By storing an `IEnumerable<string>` in my `DnaGenerator` instances, I am gaining essentially nothing. When an enumerator is requested, both lines below result in allocating a single object. It's an autogenerated object with dual personality. It is both an `IEnumerable<string>`, and an `IEnumerator<string>`.

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => _enumerable.GetEnumerator();

public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => Iterator().GetEnumerator();
```

By storing the `_enumerable` in a field I am just preventing this object from getting recycled.

Nevertheless I am still searching for ways to solve this non-issue, in a way that would allow me to keep the cached `_enumerable` field, without causing a memory leak, and without resorting to implementing a full fledged `IEnumerable<string>` from scratch as shown in @MatthewWatson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72473516/11178549). The workaround that I found is to wrap my generated DNA sequences in [`StrongBox<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1) wrappers:

```
private IEnumerable<StrongBox<string>> Iterator()
{
    while (true)
        foreach (char c in new char[] { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' })
            yield return new(new String(c, 10_000_000));
}
```

Then I have to `Unwrap` the iterator before exposing it to the external world:

```
private readonly IEnumerable<string> _enumerable;

public DnaGenerator() => _enumerable = Iterator().Unwrap();
```

Here is the `Unwrap` extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Unwraps an enumerable sequence that contains values wrapped in StrongBox instances.
/// The latest StrongBox instance is emptied when the enumerator is disposed.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> Unwrap<T>(this IEnumerable<StrongBox<T>> source)
    => new StrongBoxUnwrapper<T>(source);

private class StrongBoxUnwrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<StrongBox<T>> _source;
    public StrongBoxUnwrapper(IEnumerable<StrongBox<T>> source)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        _source = source;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(_source.GetEnumerator());
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<StrongBox<T>> _source;
        private StrongBox<T> _latest;
        public Enumerator(IEnumerator<StrongBox<T>> source)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
            _source = source;
        }
        public T Current => _source.Current.Value;
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            var moved = _source.MoveNext();
            _latest = _source.Current;
            return moved;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _source.Dispose();
            if (_latest is not null) _latest.Value = default;
        }
        public void Reset() => _source.Reset();
    }
}
```

The trick is to keep track of the latest `StrongBox<T>` that has been emitted by the enumerator, and set its [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1.value) to `default` when the enumerator is disposed.

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BaQc3A).